# SQLPLUS: TNS-style vs regular connection parameters

Tags: sqlplus

I'm wondering what the difference could be between connecting with SQLPlus using a "TNS-style" entry like

> sqlplus
> user/pass@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.70.44.28)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mdm)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))"

and "regular" connection parameters in a form like

> sqlplus user/pass@10.70.44.28:1521:mdm

To my surprise, I've encountered a case where a "regular" connection URL won't work while a "TNS-style" URL works fine.

Looking at the trace files, I see in the "regular" trace the following messages:

> (7076) [25-JUL-2023 15:05:45:555] nttbnd2addr:  *** hostname lookup failure! ***
>
> (7076) [25-JUL-2023 15:05:45:555] nttbnd2addr: exit

followed by

> (7076) [25-JUL-2023 15:05:45:555] niqme: reporting NS-12545 error as
> ORA-12545
>
> (7076) [25-JUL-2023 15:05:45:555] niomapnserror: exit
>
> (7076) [25-JUL-2023 15:05:45:555] niotns: Couldn't connect, returning 12545
>
> (7076) [25-JUL-2023 15:05:45:555] niqme: exit

and nothing like that in the "TNS-style" trace.

[image: Same parameters but different result]

Answer (score 1):

It was my mistake.

I confused JDBC syntax where you can connect to a SID using "`host:port:SID`" format with SQLPlus' EZCONNECT string where you can only connect to SERVICE_NAME using "`host:port/SERVICE_NAME`" format and not to a SID.